# Arabic Text Shows Encoded

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, vb.net

I have a problem that file encoding was windows-1256 and it shows strange text when using ie11 and arabic text, so i changed the file encoding to utf-8 and it works fine but i need to convert back the already inserted text.

am using sql server and vb.net

this is a sample text (طھط¬ط±ط¨ط©) to be changed.

Comment: Try something like [this](https://www.webutils.pl/Charset-Converter)

Comment: [Encoding.Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.convert). `windows-1256` is not a great choice as Encoding if you plan to have Web interaction. It can be used as local CodePage, but if you need to reach an international audience, it becomes a problem. `windows-1256` offers poor composition for arabic letters. It should be used only locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this

`Encoding.GetEncoding(Int32)`

For your Reference, Please See This Article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencoding?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Database -> Properties -> Options -> Collation -> Arabic_CI_AS